# For loops with multiple result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, automation

I have a following dummy data frame:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([[1,50,60],[5,70,80],[2,120,30],[3,125,450],[5,80,90],[4,100,200],[2,1000,2000],[1,10,20]],columns = ['A','B','C'])

   A     B     C
0  1    50    60
1  5    70    80
2  2   120    30
3  3   125   450
4  5    80    90
5  4   100   200
6  2  1000  2000
7  1    10    20
```

I am for loop in python at this moment and I would like to know if there is any possibility that for loop in python to generate multiple results. I would like to break the above data frame using for loop where for each variable in column A I would like to have new df and sort them based on column B and have column C multiplied by 2:

```
df1 =
   A    B     C
  1    10    40
  1    20    120
```

```
df2 =
   A     B     C

   2   120    60
   2  1000  4000
```

```
df3 =
   A     B     C
   3   125   900
```

```
df4 = 
   A     B     C
   4   100   200
```

```
df5 =
   A     B     C
   5    70    80
   5    80    90
```

I am not sure if this can be done in Python. Normally I use matlab and for this I tried the following in my python script:

```
def f(df):
    for i in np.unique(df['A'].values):
            df = df.sort_values(['A','B'])
            df = df['C'].assign(C = lambda x: x.C*2)
    print df
```

Of course this is wrong since it will not generate multiple result as df1,df2...df5 (this variables are important to be ended by 1,2,...5 such that it can be traced or followed column A of the dataframe). Could anyone help me please? I understand that this can be easily done without for loop (vectorization), but I have many unique values in column A and I would like to run a for loop on them and I would also like to learn more about loop in Python. Many thanks.

Comment: Multiple results - use a list to store previous results, return it at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is faster than `Series.unique`. 
Optionally you can save the dataframes in a dictionary.
The advantage of using a dictionary with respect to the list is that it can match the password with the value in A

```
df2=df.copy()
df2['C']=df2['C']*2
df2=df2.sort_values('B')
dfs={i:group for i,group in df2.groupby('A')}
```

---

access the dictionary based on the value in A:

```
for key in dfs:
    print(f'dfs[{key}]')
    print(dfs[key])
    print('_'*20)

dfs[1]
   A   B    C
7  1  10   80
0  1  50  240
____________________
dfs[2]
   A     B     C
2  2   120   120
6  2  1000  8000
____________________
dfs[3]
   A    B     C
3  3  125  1800
____________________
dfs[4]
   A    B    C
5  4  100  800
____________________
dfs[5]
   A   B    C
1  5  70  320
4  5  80  360
```

Comment: Wise choice of `dict` for storage. You still need to sort `B` and multiply `C` though. Can you do that in `dict` comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

Sort and multiply *before* chunking into pieces:

```
df['C'] = 2* df['C']
[group for name, group in df.sort_values(by=['A','B']).groupby('A')]
```

Or if you want a dict:

```
{name: group for name, group in df.sort_values(by=['A','B']).groupby('A')}
```

Comment: I think the list makes access difficult, it's easier to use a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I have similar answer like Ansev:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,50,60],[5,70,80],[2,120,30],[3,125,450],[5,80,90],[4,100,200],[2,1000,2000],[1,10,20]],columns = ['A','B','C'])

A = np.unique(data['A'].values)


df_result = []
for a in A:
    df1 = df.loc[df['A'] == a]
    df1 = df1.sort_values('B')
    df1 = df1.assign(C = lambda x: x.C*2)
    df_result+=[df1]
```

I am still unable to automate this for having the result as df_result1, df_result2...df_result5. What I can do is only to call the result from each loop as df_result[0], df_result[1],...df_result[4].

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is group by the column `A` and then store the resulting dataframe into a dict indexed by the value of `A`. A code to do that would be

```
df_dict = {}
for ix, gp in df.groupby('A'):
    new_df = gp.sort_values('B')
    new_df['C'] = 2*new_df['C']
    df_dict[ix] = new_df
```

Then the variable `df_list` contains all the resulting dataframes sorted by column `B` and column `C` multiplied by 2. For example

```
print(df_dict[1])
   A    B     C
  1    10    40
  1    50    120
```

Comment: then A = 1 is in position 0?

Comment: by using a `dict` instead of `list` you can index the dataframes by the value of `A` - edited

Comment: it is a success that you change the use to a dictionary, however this I already proposed, also it is not necessary to initialize an empty dictionary

Comment: you need to somehow define `df_dict` otherwise you 'll get a `NameError`

Comment: It is simply better to order before, so you don't have to use the loop order method. That's inefficient